# Google Play processing update since many days

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Its been more than 2 weeks since I have published my app on Google Play Store. It's not published yet. The Google Play console is just showing "processing update". Is anybody else facing this issue. Please help. It's a critical update that I need to push. Thanks!

Comment: facing the same. any update on it? how did you resolve?

Comment: Same issue, what to do ?